# is it possible to do this with only one var?

Tags: ios

I can't seem to figure out how to only do this with one var? So I was wondering if it's possible to even do it? or is this the only way to add a button line to all 3 UITextfields?

```
 var border = CALayer(); var border2 = CALayer(); var border3 = CALayer()
        var width = CGFloat(0.7); var width2 = CGFloat(0.7); var width3 = CGFloat(0.7)

    border.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    border2.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    border3.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor

    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: workServer.frame.size.height - width, width: 250, height: workServer.frame.size.height)
    border2.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: workUsername.frame.size.height - width, width: 250, height: workUsername.frame.size.height)
    border3.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: workPassword.frame.size.height - width, width: 250, height: workPassword.frame.size.height)

    border.borderWidth = width
    border2.borderWidth = width
    border3.borderWidth = width
    workServer.layer.addSublayer(border)
    workServer.layer.masksToBounds = true
    workUsername.layer.addSublayer(border2)
    workUsername.layer.masksToBounds = true
    workPassword.layer.addSublayer(border3)
    workPassword.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

Comment: Use a method with in parameter a textfield.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it without any `var`s:

```
    let views = [workServer, workUsername, workPassword]
    for view in views {
        let border = CALayer()
        let width = CGFloat(0.7)
        border.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height - width, width: 250, height: view.frame.size.height)
        border.borderWidth = width
        view.layer.addSublayer(border)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could write a function that does the same.

```
func addBorder (UIView *view)
{
    var border = CALayer()
    var width = CGFloat(0.7)
    border.borderColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
    border.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: view.frame.size.height - width, width: 250, height: view.frame.size.height)
    border.borderWidth = width
    view.layer.addSublayer(border)
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true;
}
```

You can call this as follows:

```
addBorder(workServer)
addBorder(workUsername)
addBorder(workPassword)
```